# Is there a way to define a max list depth?

Tags: quil

If you keep pressing the tab key on a list you end-up having a lot of levels.
Can we limit it to one level more than the last one used?

Or at least to a maximum number of levels? (4 for instance)

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Actually I was more looking for a way to configure it but I ended-up coding it myself thanks.